# Outlook 2007 Script to Add Emails from a Particular Person to Evernote 4

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, script, evernote

I need to create a rule in Outlook 2007 which will run a script when an email from a particular person is received. In particular, I want the script to add the email to my Evernote account. By the way, I don't know if this is relevant but when I go into Outlook 2007 I see an "Add to Evernote 4" button. In other words, instead of me clicking the "Add to Evernote 4" button I would like an Outlook rule to be triggered which runs a script that somehow makes the email appear in my Evernote account. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may configure Outlook to forward the messages from this person to your Evernote incoming address (which you may find at you Evernote profile).

More details about mailing stuff to Evernote available [here](http://blog.evernote.com/2010/03/16/emailing-into-evernote-just-got-better/).